# In VBScript I need to "Get Latest Version" from VSS 8

Tags: vbscript, visual-sourcesafe

Our VSS setup is like this: We have a set of unique folders with 100s of files in them. I need to, from within VBScript, get the latest version of all files in a set of folders and put them into a local directory so that other operations can be performed on them.
The reason for VBScript is, well, vague even to me. Perhaps VB or C# .NET will work as well, but for now I can only do it from within VBScript.
Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can try the [VSS automation interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509341.aspx), or if that doesn't work, just shell out to the [VSS command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4(VS.80).aspx).

[This link](http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/HelpLibDevStudio9/IHelpSccCmdLine.htm) as some sample code that may get you started.